# Function that spreads input

Tags: binary-trees, hash, binary-arithmetic

I'd like to know if there is a function $f$ from n-bit numbers to n-bit numbers that has the following characteristics:

- $f$ should be bijective
- Both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ should be calculable pretty fast
- $f$ should return a number that has no significant correlation to its input.

The rationale is this:

I want to write a  program that operates on data. Some information of the data is stored in a binary search tree where the search key is a symbol of an alphabet. With time, I add further symbols to the alphabet. New symbols simply get the next free number available. Hence, the tree will always have a small bias to smaller keys which causes more rebalancing than I think should be needed.

My idea is to mangle the symbol numbers with $f$ such that they are widely spread over the whole range of $[0,2^{64}-1]$. Since the symbol numbers only matter during input and output which happens only once, applying such a function should not be too expensive.

I thought about one iteration of the Xorshift random number generator, but I don't really know a way to undo it, although it should theoretically be possible.

Does anybody know such a function?
Is this a good idea?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but perhaps you can use a pseudorandom permutation (see for example the [Feistel cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher))

Comment: If you are essentially computing a hash function, why not use hashing?

Comment: @vonbrand Hashing is not reversible. See requirement number 2.

Comment: _Why_ does it have to be reversible? What is wrong with making it reversible by lookup?

Comment: @vonbrand I have up to about $2^30 different input values, so a lookup table would add a lot of footprint to my program.

Comment: @FUZxxl, you want to build a sarch tree on hashed inputs (and they have to be unique to make the tree work). If you are paying the cost of this hash, use a has table: Faster, no requirement of unique hash function. What is wrong with this idea? Is there some _other_ requirement that you haven't told us about?

Comment: @vonbrand I hate hash tables. Also, I am going to implement this in Haskell were immutable data structures are much simpler to use.

Comment: @FUZxxl, there is nothing mutable in a hashtable... at least not more than trees. And "I hate XXX" is hardly a technical reason.

Comment: @vonbrand Yeah, it isn't. In Haskell you can't alter variables. It's pretty simple to do efficient binary trees though. In my current application I have to repeatedly add and delete entries. Looking up in a hash table is of course not a mutating operation.

Comment: You can store (f(x),x) as keys.

Answer (score 6):

You can use *Fibonacci hashing*, namely

$\qquad h_F(k) = k \cdot \frac{\sqrt{5} - 1}{2} - \left\lfloor k \cdot  \frac{\sqrt{5} - 1}{2} \right\rfloor$.

For $k=1,\dots,n$ you get $n$ pairwise-distinct numbers (about) evenly spread in $[0,1]$. By scaling to $[1..M]$ and rounding (down), you get about evenly spread numbers in that interval.

For example, these are $h_F(1), \dots, h_F(200)$ scaled to $[0..10000]$ (left original sequence, right sorted):

[image]

This is an instance of what Knuth calls *multiplicative hashing*. For $w$ the computer's word size, $A$ some integer relatively prime to $w$ and $M$ the number of addresses needed, we use

$\qquad h(k) = \left\lfloor M \left( \bigl( k \cdot \frac{A}{w}\bigr) \mod 1 \right) \right\rfloor$

as hashing function. The above follows with $A/w = \phi^{-1} = \frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$ (make sure you can compute it with a sufficient precision). While this also works with any other irrational number besides $\phi^{-1}$, it is one of only two numbers that lead to the "most uniformly distributed" numbers.

Find more in [The Art of Computer Programming](http://www-cs-staff.stanford.edu/~uno/taocp.html), Volume 3 by Donald Knuth (chapter 6.4 from page 513 in the second edition). In particular you'll find why the resulting numbers are pairwise distinct (at least if $n \ll M$) and how to compute the inverse function if you use natural $A$ and $w$ instead of $\phi^{-1}$.

Comment: How to calculate $f^{-1}$ efficiently?

Comment: @frafl I hope my edit addresses your concern somewhat. It's clear, though, that these hashing techniques are nor particularly designed to be efficiently invertible.

Comment: Yes it does, I'll upvote it, however I would not recommend it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

For $k$-bit inputs, this function works:

$\mathrm{hash}(n) = (n \bmod 2^{\lceil\frac{k}{2}\rceil})\cdot 2^{\lceil\frac{k}{2}\rceil} + n \,\mathrm{div}\, 2^{\lceil\frac{k}{2}\rceil}$

This is reversible, in that $\mathrm{hash}(\mathrm{hash}(n)) = n$, and has non-sequential pairs $\{n,m\}, n < m$, where $\mathrm{hash}(m) < \mathrm{hash}(n)$. Beware that output and input may correlate, especially if your input is in $\{1,\dots,2^{\lceil\frac{k}{2}\rceil}-1\}$.

Ref: [Reversible hash function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273466/reversible-hash-function)

Comment: This looks simple and nice. I'm going to test that one.

Comment: 1. Depending on the input, it may produce heavy correlation (up to $1$ for Spearman's $\rho$)

2. This is for 32 bits, not for 64 bits

3. Could you please write this in a language-independent way?

Comment: it's pretty clear! for 64-bit (0x00000000FFFFFFFF) and you should shift(<<) 32 bits. This function is simple, practical and fast enough in practice.

Comment: But why don't you use a permutation of the bits, that does not map every $x \in \{1,\dots,2^{32}-1\}$ to $2^{32}x$? As stated above this clearly violates the correlation condition demanded by the OP.